# In Razor View how to access the Id of dynamically created number of textbox

Tags: razor

I am trying to create a number of text box dynamically in my Razor view. How can I ensure a different id is assigned to each of the text box dynamically?  My objective is to access the numeric value entered in the dynamic textbox (QuestionCount) and calculate the sum of values entered.

Below is the part of code used in my view.

```
@foreach (var QP_Count in ViewBag.NonUniformTempCount)
{
 var str = @ViewBag.NonUniformTempNames[tempindex];
 <b>@str</b>
 for (int QCount = 1; QCount <= QP_Count; QCount++)
   {
     **<br /> <b>@QCount</b>  <b>@Html.TextBox("QuestionCount")</b>**                           
   }
 tempindex++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Order to give different id's to dynamicaly generated textboxes try this :-

```
@foreach (var QP_Count in ViewBag.NonUniformTempCount)
{
  var str = @ViewBag.NonUniformTempNames[tempindex];
  <b>@str</b>
  for (int QCount = 1; QCount <= QP_Count; QCount++)
  {
    <br /> <b>@QCount</b> <b>@Html.TextBox("QuestionCount",null,new{ id = "Question-" + @QCount + @QP_Count })</b>                          
  }
  tempindex++;
}
```